# returning a value in a function with a type given

Tags: c#

I have a class which is dividable.

```
public class A
    {
        private static A Divide(double a, A b)
        {
            // some code to divide
            return b;
        }
        public static A operator / (double a, A b)
        {
            return Divide(a, b);
        }
    }
    public class B : A
    {
        private static B Divide(double a, B b)
        {
            // some code to divide
            return b;
        }
        public static B operator / (double a, B b)
        {
            return Divide(a, b);
        }
    }
```

As it is shown, division of class A and B should represent type A and B, respectively. However, I cannot figure out how to make Divide function once only on class A. Is there a way to use such things as templates in C++?

Comment: which is it, C# or C++? there's kind of a big difference.

Comment: (judging by your code i'm going with C#)

Comment: @TimothyGroote Read it again, its C# OP is just asking if there is something like 'templates from c++' in c#

Comment: i think OP is after operator overloading. have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/overloadable-operators\

Comment: I'm using C#, @TimothyGroote

Comment: Those are static methods, there's nothing forcing you to implement `Divide` on `B`.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want them to be static in the first place. also, if you do not make them static, and only define the function *once* in `A`, then all instances of `B` will have it. (though the `private` scope is obscuring from `B`, and you should make it either `protected` or `public`)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your code is confusing putting static methods inside class hierarchy with accepting specific class. It begs for use of virtual methods - where you can override the class if you wish to use specific instance type and if you don't it uses the same.

If you want a simpler way of having a template work with multiple class types independent of the class - the proper way to implement this in C# is Generics:

```
public static class Templates{
        public static T Divide<T>(double a, T item)
        {
            // some code to divide
            return item;
        }
}
```

and call it like:

```
    Templates.Divide(a, b);
```

Comment: I don't get it. Do you mean I should make a new template class in order to make a divide function and operator which acts only at few classes? Or is there a way to define a function in class? Or should I define a Templates class inside class A?